# move_uploaded_file and relative path to destination in public_html in home directory?

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm using OpenSuse 12.2 now. To learn and test PHP code I use public_html directory in my home folder: /home/wojtek/public_html/ I access project files in the following way:

```
http://localhost/~wojtek/projects/foo/bar.php
```

But I have not clue how to make move_uploaded_file to work. The server root is /srv/www. I set upload_tmp_dir to /srv/www/tmp (I have really no idea where it should go).

When I set destination of move_upladed_file to /srv/www/images, files landed there. But I'd like to make use of public_html folder as I'm keeping all my files there.

For example having:
public_html/projects/foo/
public_html/projects/foo/bar.php
public_html/projects/foo/images/baz.jpg

Can I somehow use the relative destination ('images/') of move_uploaded_file in the bar.php? So that I can access images relatively in IMG tag like  from bar.php?

Sorry if it sounds a bit chaotic but I'm new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

No you wont be able to access the `/srv/www/images` folder from the `/home/wojtek/public_html/projects/foo/bar.php` web page.

Id suggest either

1) setting the `move_uploaded_file` to `/home/wojtek/public_html/projects/foo/images`

or

2) using a symbolic link to access the images folder from your public_html folder:

```
cd /home/wojtek/public_html/projects/foo
ln -s /srv/www/images/
```

and then it will appear that the images are stored in `/home/wojtek/public_html/projects/foo/images`, but they will actually still be here `/srv/www/images`

Its possible that you may run into trouble with permissions using this method however

Comment: Thanks. As the server root is /srv/www, I think that /home/wojtek is outside of its scope. On the other hand, the server is aware of the public_html in my home dir, since I access it as follows localhost/~wojtek/projects/foo/bar.php. Is it possible for example to do it like this: PATH_TO_THE_CURRENT_SCRIPT . 'images/' or kinda similar?

Comment: Yes you can do that. `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` will resolve to the directory as defined by apache for the site - in your case `/home/wojtek/public_html/`.

Comment: All the information if you need it: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: hi again! Sorry for not replying for 3 days as I was busy. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] returns not /home/wojtek/public_html/ but /srv/www/htdocs. On the other hand, the document under the following address: http://localhost/~wojtek/headfirst/ch05/guitarwars/index.php when I issue echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; returns /~wojtek/headfirst/ch05/guitarwars/index.php. What gives? :)

Comment: So you say that I can't move a tmp file from /srv/www to my public_html? Maybe I can overwrite global settings? Kinda local temporary dir, local server root?

Comment: Have you tried? move_uploaded_file("filename", "/home/wojtek/public_html/projects/foo/images"); If this is such an issue, why bother with the Home folders at all?

Comment: Problem solved. I turned on error reporting and it turned out that I had incorrect permissions for image/ folder. Thank you for your help!